# regex match all except two characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the first attribute before both : and ! so either PASS SKIP OR FAIL

```
PASS   : test::subtest()  message
SKIP :    test::subtest2()  message
FAIL! : test::subtest3()  message
```

The following regex works

```
([^:]*)
```

but it also matches the ! with FAIL!

So I tried

```
([^:!]*)
```

but that doesn't work it doesn't match FAIL! at all.

EDIT
sorry debugging wrong thing we need to look at full regex

```
if($line =~ m/([^:!]+):\s?([^:]*)::([^(]*)(\([^\)]*\))(.*)/)
```

Comment: Works for me, could you post a complete example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you provide more code? It works for me:

```
ckruse@achilles ~ $ perl -e 'print "FAIL! : blabla" =~ /^([^:!]+)/ ? "yes: $1" : "no","\n"'

yes: FAIL
```

Comment: Hey sorry I realised it's because I'm using a longer regex that affects the matching. I need to fix after this match right now I will only match a : after I need to include ! also sometimes how do I do that?

Comment: Add a [:!] after the part regex, e.g. like follows: /^([^:!]+)\s*[:!]/

Answer (score 2):

If you know that what you're looking for is in the beginning of the line, then this should work:

```
^([^:!]+)[:!]
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you out

```
([^:!]\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like:

```
/([^:!\s]+)!? \s* : \s* ([^:\s]*) :: ([^(]*)(\([^\)]*\))(.*)/x
```

What I did was basically add `!?` after `([^:!]*)`